# what is the mapping reduction of $A_{TM}$ to $\overline{CF_{TM}}$

Tags: computability, computational-mathematics, context-free-grammar, turing-machines

first post here :)

I am trying to find a reduction from $A_{TM}$ to $\overline{CF_{TM}}$.

definitions:

$CF_{TM}\:=\:\left\{<M>| M\:is\:a\:TM\:and\:L\left(M\right)\:is\:a\:context-free\:language\right\}$

$A_{TM}\:=\:\left\{<M,W> |\:M\:is\:a\:TM\:and\:M\:accepts\:w\right\}$

I am having a hard time showing that or find a mapping reduction that would apply $x ∈ A_{TM}  ⇔  f(x) ∈ \overline{CF_{TM}}$

Can't find such reduction unfortunately. struggling hours with it.

would really appreciate help with it

Comment: There is some context in this question, but it would help to give the source of the problem and the definition of $A_{TM}$.  Knowing the class you are in would help, and knowing whether you have seen Rice's theorem.

Comment: @CarlMummert - sorry i wasn't at home before. i am familar with Rice's theorem and the class is computability and complexity. help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what $A_{TM}$ is, unfortunately.   Rice's theorem shows that $0' \leq_m  \overline{CF_{TM}}$, so it is enough to show that $A_{TM} \leq_m 0'$.

Comment: I should give more detail -  because $\emptyset$ is context free, $\emptyset \not \in \overline{CF_{TM}}$, and so by the proof of Rice's theorem there is a reduction from the halting prolem to $\overline{CF_{TM}}$

Comment: @CarlMummert, very sorry. i've added the definition now. hoping you can help me with it

Comment: You can just follow the proof of Rice's theorem.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understand it. that is why i asked here hoping to learn from it